# php get records from mysql only when dosent have duplicated value

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates

mysql like that

```
=======================
| id    |  name       |
| 1     | jhon        |  
| 2     | sarah       |
| 3     | suzan       |
| 4     | jhon        |
| 5     | ahmed       |
=======================
```

my expected result is

```
sarah
suszan
ahmed
```

want to remove `jhon` or any value name are duplicated 
i tried to use

```
SELECT * FROM  table WHERE id={$id} GROUP BY name
```

but it's only displaying the duplicated values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use HAVING

```
SELECT `name` FROM `table` GROUP BY `name` HAVING COUNT(`name`) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

To get unique values, you can use below :

// This will return unique values

```
SELECT DISTINCT `name` FROM `table`;
```

Comment: He's not asking for distinct but for name having count 1 as in @Talgat answer